# Group values by unique values in same column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a table to wordpress meta_data for which looks something like this:

```
meta_key                meta_value       post_id
addressSuburb           South Bank       12
addressSuburb           West End         13
addressState            QLD              12
addressState            VIC              13
```

The query I use to get the data is:

```
SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p on p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'addressSuburb' OR pm.meta_key = 'addressState'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_type = 'listings
```

What I need is to get is have all the suburbs grouped by the states they are in. I'm currently doing this by getting all the addressSuburb and addressState data and using the post_id to find out which suburbs are in which state (in PHP, after the query has returned the data). The end result I require is as such:

```
QLD [ suburb1, suburb2, suburb3 ]
VIC [...etc]
```

Is this transform of the data possible using just a SQL query? If so, how?

Comment: You'll want to sort by state and then suburb, I suppose.
Are you using WP_Query or is that your actual SQL?

Comment: @janh2 This is part of a plugin, this is the actual query. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by sort by state then suburb?

Comment: You'd need to join postmeta twice so you can differentiate between state and suburb (use table aliases), then add `ORDER BY state.meta_value ASC, suburb.meta_value ASC`.
However, I'd recommend letting [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) do that.